# How to get better Performance for Multi-Language Content MVC Pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, model, multilingual

Okay, you might think this is a duplicate question, but it's not I assure you.

I already have everything built using mvc routing and culture info.

So I just need to know how to store and get the text content for each language setting.

There are some requirements in my case:

1. I want the language texts data to be configured in Database
2. I want to load all the language texts from database on the server-side on application startup
3. I want the minimal cpu clock usage (best performance)
4. I am using EntityFramework 6 for Database Access

I was thinking about getting all the info from the database, and then fill each model (a model for each view) with dictionaries for each text property in page, is this a good approach?

Like having something like this:

```
//This might not compile, I just "hand-write" it here without VS to show you example

public class HomeViewModel {

    Dictionary<CultureInfo, String> title { get; set; }
    Dictionary<CultureInfo, String> customMessageBanner { get; set; }
    Dictionary<CultureInfo, String> myFooterText { get; set; }

}

public class TitleDbItem {

    int TitleDbItemId {get; set;}
    string cultureInfo {get; set;}
    string Text {get; set;}

}
```

I just don't know if Dictionary isn't a little bit heavy for this purpose (like using a cannon to kill a fly), since I will be just using two languages (at the moment)

Using this approach if I want to add more languages in future, I just need to add a new row to the table TitleDbItem...

I just wanna know if there is any best approach for this?

I read some guides using Resource Files, but since I am using dynamic data from Database, maybe it's not good to generate resources files in runtime on the server right?

Will this approach be much time consuming for CPU and Performance? 
Please any feedback is welcome, I am looking for a better solution..

Thank you!

Comment: You should use a ListDictionary instead which is recommended for collection with few items. But even using a Dictionary will not impact heavily your performance...

Comment: Thank you for your answer @JonathanMagnan, didn't know about that, I will change it! Thank you so much, if someone out there came out with a better solution, please write it as an answer or maybe even you Jonathan, that's better than mine! Thank you!